# Send POST request from Spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-portlet-mvc

I have a question to you. Let me explain the situation. We have a jsp page, there is a post form here with some inputs. When user enter some data and submit the form, my spring controller handles this request, transforms income data and then I should send it's trasformed data with post request to another site with the client redirection. In other words I want to know is it some oppotunity to use `response.sendRedirect("some other website url")` with post request in my controller? Or how I can do it another way? 
For example simple form:

```
<form action="myServerSideUrl" method="post>
   <input type="text" name="Input1"/>
   <input type="text" name="Input1"/>
   <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

When user submit it, it comes to server, then for example I sum Input1 and Input2 (Input3), and then I want to redirect user to another site with Input3 POST request.

Comment: I believe redirecting to HTTP code 307 allows you to redirect the POST content aswell

Comment: Can you post an example please? @DanielHigueras

Answer (score 1):

You may use Spring's own [`RestTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) or a simple `java.net.URLConnection` (but you have to write a bit more code) to make a `POST` request in your controller.

So upon receiving the request in your [`@Controller`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Controller.html) you can just forward it wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
       <html:form action="changePassword" method="POST"
            commandName="changePasswordForm">
            <label> <html:password path="password" id="oldPassword"
                    maxlength="128" class="input" required="required"
                    placeholder="Current Password" />
            </label>
            <label> <html:password path="newPassword" id="password"
                    maxlength="15" required="required" class="input"
                    placeholder="New Password" />
            </label>
            <label> <html:password path="confirmPassword"
                    id="confirmNewPassword" maxlength="15" required="required"
                    class="input" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
            </label>
            <label> <html:input path="" type="submit" value="SAVE"
                     />
            </label>
    </html:form>
```

Spring Controller is below :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "changePassword", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String changePassword( @ModelAttribute(value = "searchForm")        SearchForm searchForm,
                              Model inModel,
                              HttpServletRequest inRequest )
    {
    String viewName ="changePassPage";
    // do something logic related to change password.
    return viewName ;
    }
```

Form Bean Or POJO Model in spring:

```
   public class SearchForm
    {
        private String password;
        private String newPassword;
        private String confirmPassword;
        //setter & getter;
    }
```

You can try with Spring Post Example

Comment: Thank you. But I don't need to redirect to my view (viewName in you example). I want to redirect user with post request to another site.